# Question about linearity on tensor product space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $U$ be an finite dimensional inner product space. I'm trying to show that the two vector spaces $U \otimes U^*$ and $\mathcal L(U, U)$ are isomorphic, where $\mathcal L(U, U)$ is the space of all linear transformations on $U$ and $U^*$ is the dual space of $U$. I believe the map $u \otimes f \mapsto u f (\cdot)$ should work. I have been able to prove the map is bijective, but I'm stuck in showing it's linear in the first place. I took to arbitrary tensors $u_1 \otimes f_1$ and $u_2 \otimes f_2$ and tried showing the additive property, but don't seem to able to get $u_1 f_1(\cdot) + u_2 f_2(\cdot)$ as I should. Maybe this map simply doesn't work?

Comment: Not every element of $U \otimes U^*$ is of the form $u \otimes f$. So, it is not correct to say "the map $u \otimes f \mapsto uf(\cdot)$". *Hint*: What does the universal property of the tensor product says?

Comment: @joeren1020 If $U$ is infinite dimensional, then the two spaces are not isomorphic. You need to apply a suitable completion to the image of $U \otimes U^*$ under your mapping.

Comment: @azif00 The universal property says that for any bilinear map from $U\times U^*$ to $\mathcal L(U)$ there is a unique linear map from $U \otimes U^*$ to $\mathcal L(U)$. In particular, if I define the map $(u, f) \mapsto uf(\cdot)$ that goes from $U \times U^*$ to $\mathcal L(U)$, which is bilinear, then the universal property guarantees that the map $u \otimes f \mapsto u f(\cdot)$ is linear.
Is this correct?

Comment: @joeren1020 Yes, that is correct